# Creating highlighted results in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have output from a table that I want highlighted should a certain requirement not be met.  I have it working fine for one section, but then when I use the code on a QofQ after an inner join of two tables, it doesn't work.

I can see when I dump the variables that they are correct and I know 100% that one of the companies contains no negative data so should display correctly but both companies are displaying in red.

I'm obviously not seeing something or does QofQ have limitations that are causing this ?

I'm still learning so please be kind :)

Queries :

```
<cfquery name="suppNeg" datasource="users">
    SELECT companies.subID, companies.companyID, companies.suppName
         , suppresult_old.companyID, suppresult_old.O18, suppresult_old.O19
         , suppresult_old.O20, suppresult_old.O22, suppresult_old.WDPVC1
         , suppresult_old.WDPVC2, quarterID
    FROM suppresult_old INNER JOIN companies
           ON suppresult_old.companyID=companies.companyID
    WHERE quarterID = 8
    AND   companies.subID = #session.auth.companyID#
    ORDER BY companies.suppName ASC

</cfquery> 

 <cfquery dbtype="query" name="subs">
    SELECT  DISTINCT suppName, companyID, subID
    FROM    suppNeg
    ORDER BY suppName ASC
</cfquery>


   <cfquery name="columntotals" datasource="users">
    SELECT O18,O19,O20,O22, WDPVC1, WDPVC2
    FROM   suppresult_old INNER JOIN companies
              ON suppresult_old.companyID=companies.companyID
    WHERE  quarterID = 8
    AND    companies.subID = #session.auth.companyID#
</cfquery>

<cfset O18Value = valueList(columntotals.O18) />
<cfset O18total = listToArray(O18Value) />
<cfset O19Value = valueList(columntotals.O19) />
<cfset O19total = listToArray(O19Value) />
<cfset O20Value = valueList(columntotals.O20) />
<cfset O20total = listToArray(O20Value) />
<cfset O22Value = valueList(columntotals.O22) />
<cfset O22total = listToArray(O22Value) />

<cfset WDPVC1Value = valueList(columntotals.WDPVC1) />
<cfset WDPVC1total = listToArray(WDPVC1Value) />

<cfset WDPVC2Value = valueList(columntotals.WDPVC2) />
<cfset WDPVC2total = listToArray(WDPVC2Value) /> 



<cfquery name="suppliers" datasource="users">
    SELECT suppName, companyID, subID
    FROM companies
    WHERE subID=#session.auth.companyID#
    ORDER BY suppName ASC

</cfquery>
```

Output :

```
<cfoutput query="subs">
    <div class="container" width="1100">
        <div class="row">
        <a href="2tierReport.cfm?quarterID=8&companyID=#companyID#">
        <cfif (arraysum(O18total)) LT 0>
            <div class ="col-sm-4 supphighlight1">
                <h4>

                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:##ffffff; font-size: 32px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;#subs.suppName#</strong></a>
                </h4> 
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href="2tierReport.cfm?quarterID=8&companyID=#companyID#">
            <cfelseif (arraysum(O19total)) LT 0>
            <div class ="col-sm-4 supphighlight1">
                <h4>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:##ffffff; font-size: 32px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;#subs.suppName#</strong>
                </h4>
            </div>
                </a>
                <a href="2tierReport.cfm?quarterID=8&companyID=#companyID#">
            <cfelseif (arraysum(O20total)) LT 0>
            <div class ="col-sm-4 supphighlight1">
                <h4>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:##ffffff; font-size: 32px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;#subs.suppName#</strong>
                </h4> 
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="2tierReport.cfm?quarterID=8&companyID=#companyID#"> 
            <cfelseif (arraysum(O22total)) lt 0>
            <div class ="col-sm-4 supphighlight1">
                <h4>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:##ffffff; font-size: 32px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;#subs.suppName#</strong>
                </h4>
                    </div>
                </a> 
                <a href="2tierReport.cfm?quarterID=8&companyID=#companyID#">    
            <cfelseif (arraysum(WDPVC1total)) LT 0>
            <div class ="col-sm-4 supphighlight1">
                <h4>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:##ffffff; font-size: 32px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;#subs.suppName#</strong>
                </h4>
            </div>
            </a>
                <a href="2tierReport.cfm?quarterID=8&companyID=#companyID#">
            <cfelseif (arraysum(WDPVC2total)) LT 0>
            <div class ="col-sm-4 supphighlight1">
                <h4>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:##ffffff; font-size: 32px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;#subs.suppName#</strong>
                </h4>
            </div>
                </a>

            <cfelse> 
        <a href="suppReports_admin.cfm?quarterID=8&companyID=#companyID#">
            <div class ="col-sm-4 supphighlight">
                <h4>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" style="color:##ffffff; font-size: 32px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;#subs.suppName#</strong>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </a>
        ....
```

Comment: I noticed the query compares subID to companyID: `...AND companies.subID=#session.auth.companyID#`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Not a typo @Ageax - the companies table contains a column subID which is how we distinguish if a company belongs to a particular group.  ie Company2 belongs to a group of companies that report to Company1.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, parent / child relationship. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot to digest, without any data samples, but I'll take a stab at it :) I think the problem is that the code is comparing apples and oranges. The "sub" query contains the details for *individual* companies and subId's. (I've no idea what the real data looks like, so the samples below are just for illustration)

[image: Company Detail]

However, the `cfif` comparisons calculate the overall total for *all* companies and subId's. So if the overall total for O20 (O18, etc..) is negative, then it'll be negative for every company in the cfoutput.

[image: Company Totals]

[Runnable TryCF.com Example](https://trycf.com/gist/4998d2f1da57be7afc3a9110399dafe5/acf2016?theme=monokai)

If all you want is the totals, by companyId and subId, it's much easier to calculate that in SQL. Instead of all the `ValueList()`, `ArraySum()` and QoQ's, use the SQL aggregate function [SUM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I don't know which DBMS you're using, but something like this should work in most any database:

*Note: I "guessed" that quarterID is a column in the suppresult_old table*

```
<!--- NOT TESTED --->
<cfquery name="totalsByCompany" datasource="users">
    SELECT companies.subID
          , companies.companyID
          , companies.suppName
          , suppresult_old.quarterID
          , SUM(suppresult_old.O18) AS O18Total
          , SUM(suppresult_old.O19) AS O19Total
          , SUM(suppresult_old.O20) AS O20Total
          , SUM(suppresult_old.O22) AS O22Total
          , SUM(suppresult_old.WDPVC1) AS WDPVC1Total
          , SUM(suppresult_old.WDPVC2) AS WDPVC2Total
    FROM suppresult_old 
          INNER JOIN companies ON suppresult_old.companyID=companies.companyID
    WHERE suppresult_old.quarterID = 8
    AND   companies.subID= <cfqueryparam value="#session.auth.companyID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    GROUP BY companies.subID
          , companies.companyID
          , companies.suppName
          , suppresult_old.quarterID
    ORDER BY companies.suppName ASC
</cfquery>
```

Then in your cfoutput, use the calculated SUM's:

```
<cfoutput query="totalsByCompany">
    .... 
    <cfif O18total LT 0> .... code here
    <cfelseif O19total LT 0>.... code here
    <cfelse> ...
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

---

*Aside:* If you're new to S.O., might want to take a gander at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Putting together (the smallest possible) self-contained example demonstrating the problem makes it a LOT easier for others to assist, and less likely the question will be [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) as too broad :) Also, tools like https://trycf.com and https://sqlfiddle.com are great for sharing runnable examples.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ageax !  It worked perfectly and thank you for your explanation.  I was bashing my head against my laptop.  I will have a look at the links you've provided too.